# NetSuite dialog box with text field input (SuiteScript 1.0)

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm currently using Suitescript 1.0 we haven't made the leap to 2.0 yet and very well may this year. However, in the interim I'm looking for advice on how to create a dialog box with user input. I have looked all over SuiteAnswers and haven't had any luck.

Is this possible with 1.0?
Can the function be used in a User Event Script?
Can you provide examples or a link?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think there is one... you might want to add a custom HTML field and display a normal prompt.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I upvoted your response because it's accurate but only did half of what I needed. Unfortunately I needed to pass a variable back out of the inline HTML field. _(I didn't mention that previously because I assumed I would be able to retrieve the variable and continue using it.)_

In turn what I had to do was re-direct to a back-end suitelet and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else who are curious what I did:
I created an inline HTML field and used it to push the standard JS below to test what I was looking for. I found that it was limited for my needs and unusable, it may be useful to someone else though. What I was hoping for was to hold the person variable and use it later in my user event script to set that as a field value in view mode. It was not possible to hold the data within the variable though.

If anyone finds a method to use this and still retrieve that information, please let me know.

As mentioned in my response to felipechang I created a suitelet to do all of the operations I needed. That being said, here's the code I initially tested with. I created a button called "Test" that would trigger the function onclick.

```js
var inline_html = '<html>';
 inline_html += '<body>';
 inline_html += '<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>';
 inline_html += '<p id="demo"></p>';
 inline_html += '<script>';
 inline_html += 'function myFunction() {';
 inline_html += 'var person = prompt("Please enter your name", "Harry Potter");';
 inline_html += 'if (person != null) {';
 inline_html += 'alert("Hello " + person + "! How are you today?");';
 inline_html += '}';
 inline_html += '}';
 inline_html += '</script>';
 inline_html += '</body>';
 inline_html += '</html>';
  
nlapiSetFieldValue('custrecord_inline_html', inline_html);
  
form.addButton('custpage_revised', 'test', "myFunction()");
```